# Managing many projects with different SCM

Tags: git, svn, version-control, project, bazaar

So suppose that I'm working / contributing to 10 different project, some using git, some using bzr and some using SVN (for example).

I would like to keep everything in a single directory tree, and be able to do some SCM-agnostic operations on all of them.

I normally work with Emacs+git+magit and org-mode for keeping my notes, and I used git-submodules when I git is the only software used.

I like the approach of (for example) mr.developer, a zc.buildout recipe, the problem is that is only working for python projects, and I would like to have something more generic...

Any idea/suggestions?

EDIT: this "metaproject" should also be a way to remember to myself what I'm currently working on and keep a status for each project. The idea is to integrate such a tool with emacs+orgmode.
At the moment I haven't seen anything really useful, one idea would be to write something in python myself, there is a lot of code (for example in mr.developer) which I could steal to manage different repositories.

Comment: Collect them all under git clones? e.g. git-svn

Comment: Not really, it's only reliable for svn and not for bzr/hg for example...

Answer (score 0):

I would use bazaar with the [bzr-externals](https://launchpad.net/bzr-externals) plugin because bazaar has very good foreign vcs support (via svn, git and hg plugins) and externals works great for working with multi-module/meta projects.

Comment: It's actually nice, but I don't think I will use anything like this.
This project should not just help me using the different SCMS, but I would like to track down anything that could be useful.

For example in projects where I contribute seldomly links to bug reports and similar issues.
I created a project [link](https://github.com/AndreaCrotti/project-organizer), so I think I'll proceed with the handmade solution...

Comment: So you want to manage plain directories with this tool too? What types of operations do you want on these plain directories? You can possibly just locally version control the other stuff too.

Comment: It's not a good idea to version everything, and surely not everything under the same base repository.

Anyway her https://github.com/AndreaCrotti/project-organizer/blob/master/projects.ini I'm starting to write a configuration file that declares what I would like to have...